# Microsoft Access: Saving combo box data from form to table

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010, ms-access-2007

I have a table that stores data entered by a user in a form. All of the data entered in the form saves properly in the table except for those fields chosen from a combo box. I have checked to make sure that all of these combo box selections in the Form Design View are bound to the associated table fields in the underlying data.

Currently, I have the data type for those fields in the design view of the table set as "Short Text". I am wondering if the problem is that I need to set the data type to a different type, or if there is something else causing this problem.

Comment: Please show us the data source and row source properties of the combo box, as well as the structure of the table your form is saving to. Try to make the question minimal, complete and verifiable (https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I'd try changing the data type to Text and see if that works.  As long as the fields are bound to the controls, there's no other reason why some would work and some wouldn't except for incompatible data types.

Comment: Text and Short Text are really the same data type (Long Text is same as Memo). Since combobox columns are really text, any of the combobox column values should save into text field, so I think something else is going on.

Answer (score 0):

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit
Dim stay As String
Function EnableInfo()

    Me.ADescription.Locked = False
    Me.ComboVendor.Locked = False
    Me.ComboVendor.Locked = False
    Me.onHand.Locked = False
    Me.onOrder.Locked = False
    Me.CostB.Locked = False
    Me.ListPriceB.Locked = False

End Function

Function DisableInfo()

    Me.ADescription.Locked = True
    Me.ComboVendor.Locked = True
    Me.onHand.Locked = True
    Me.onOrder.Locked = True
    Me.CostB.Locked = True
    Me.ListPriceB.Locked = True

End Function

'------------------------------------------------------------
' Function that disables/enable when command buttons when ADD and Edit are clicked!
'------------------------------------------------------------
Function AddEdit()

    Me.CmdAdd.Enabled = False
    Me.CmdEdit.Enabled = False
    Me.CmdExit.Enabled = False
    Me.CmdSave.Enabled = True
    Me.CmdCancel.Enabled = True

    Me.AllowAdditions = True
    Me.AllowDeletions = True
    Me.AllowEdits = True

    Call EnableInfo

End Function

'------------------------------------------------------------
' Function that disables/enable when command buttons when Save and Cancel are clicked!
'------------------------------------------------------------
Function SaveCancel()

    Me.CmdAdd.Enabled = True
    Me.CmdEdit.Enabled = True
    Me.CmdExit.Enabled = True
    Me.CmdSave.Enabled = False
    Me.CmdCancel.Enabled = False

    Call DisableInfo


End Function

'------------------------------------------------------------
' Function that enables navigation buttons
'------------------------------------------------------------
Function EnableNavigation()

    Me.cmdFirst.Enabled = True
    Me.cmdNext.Enabled = True
    Me.cmdPrevious.Enabled = True
    Me.cmdlast.Enabled = True

End Function


'------------------------------------------------------------
' Function that disables navigation buttons
'------------------------------------------------------------
Function DisableNavigation()

    Me.cmdFirst.Enabled = False
    Me.cmdNext.Enabled = False
    Me.cmdPrevious.Enabled = False
    Me.cmdlast.Enabled = False

End Function


'------------------------------------------------------------
' Function when the ADD button is clicked
'------------------------------------------------------------
Private Sub CmdAdd_Click()

    PartIDtext.SetFocus
    stay = PartIDtext.Value
    Me.DataEntry = True
    Call EnableInfo
    Call AddEdit
    Call DisableNavigation

End Sub

'------------------------------------------------------------
' Function when the CANCEL button is clicked
'------------------------------------------------------------
Private Sub CmdCancel_Click()

    Call SaveCancel
    Call DisableInfo
    Call EnableNavigation
    Me.Undo
    Me.DataEntry = False
    Me.RecordsetClone.FindFirst "partID = " & stay
    Me.Bookmark = Me.RecordsetClone.Bookmark



End Sub

'------------------------------------------------------------
' Function when the EDIT button is clicked
'------------------------------------------------------------
Private Sub CmdEdit_Click()

    Call AddEdit
    Call EnableInfo
    Call DisableNavigation
    PartIDtext.SetFocus
    stay = PartIDtext.Value



End Sub

'------------------------------------------------------------
' Function when the EXIT button is clicked
'------------------------------------------------------------
Private Sub CmdExit_Click()

    DoCmd.Close

End Sub

'------------------------------------------------------------
' Function when the SAVE button is clicked
'------------------------------------------------------------
Private Sub CmdSave_Click()

        ADescription = Trim(ADescription.Value)
        stay = Me.PartIDtext.Value

        If IsNull(Me.ADescription) Or Len(Me.ADescription) < 5 Then
            MsgBox "Please enter a description of at least 5 characters"
            Me.ADescription.SetFocus


        ElseIf IsNull(Me.onHand) Or (Me.onHand) < 0 Then
            MsgBox "On hand must have a value greater than 0"
            Me.onHand.SetFocus

        ElseIf IsNull(Me.ComboVendor) Then
            MsgBox "select one"
            Me.onHand.SetFocus

        ElseIf IsNull(Me.onOrder) Or (Me.onOrder) < 0 Then
            MsgBox "On order must have a value greater than 0"
            Me.onOrder.SetFocus

        ElseIf IsNull(Me.CostB) Or (Me.CostB) < 0 Then
            MsgBox "Cost must have a value greater than 0"
            Me.CostB.SetFocus

        ElseIf IsNull(Me.ListPriceB) Or (Me.ListPriceB) < (Me.CostB) Then
            MsgBox "List price must be greater than cost!"
            Me.ListPriceB.SetFocus

        Else
            Me.DataEntry = False
            Me.RecordsetClone.FindFirst "partID = " & stay
            Me.Bookmark = Me.RecordsetClone.Bookmark

            Call SaveCancel
            Call DisableInfo
            Call EnableNavigation

        End If
End Sub


'------------------------------------------------------------
' CmdNext
'------------------------------------------------------------
Private Sub CmdNext_Click()

    On Error Resume Next
    DoCmd.GoToRecord , "", acNext

End Sub


'------------------------------------------------------------
' CmdPrevious
'------------------------------------------------------------
Private Sub CmdPrevious_Click()

    On Error Resume Next
    DoCmd.GoToRecord , "", acPrevious

End Sub


'------------------------------------------------------------
' CmdFirst
'------------------------------------------------------------
Private Sub CmdFirst_Click()

    DoCmd.GoToRecord , "", acFirst

End Sub


'------------------------------------------------------------
' CmdLast
'------------------------------------------------------------
Private Sub CmdLast_Click()

    DoCmd.GoToRecord , "", acLast

End Sub
```